# Windows 7 ZIP folders not extracting

Tags: windows-7, zip

I am helping a client who has a problem with Windows zip folders. For any zip folder, he can open the folder and see the contents, but if he does a copy and paste to a different location nothing happens, same if he drags the contents to a different location, e.g. desktop.

I've tried many different cut and pastes, and he hasn't had a virus, if I send the files uncompressed they are fine. I can't understand why this would be, any ideas?

Comment: Download 7-zip and try again. What zip tool are you using ?

Comment: @Devid No tool just the normal Windows 7 Compressed/ZIP Folders, should have made that clearer.

Comment: Ok, than download 7-zip go here: http://sourceforge.net/p/sevenzip/discussion/45797/thread/49e6a4d4/

Comment: @Devid I don't want to download a utility I need to find out what is wrong with the normal folders and get that working again.

Comment: Can you try to right click on the zip file, and find option to "Extract All"? (I've tested this on Windows 8, but pretty sure Windows 7 have the same feature)

Comment: try to create a zip file at the desetination just as a test. Try also like renaming a.txt to a.zip  He could of course try renaming the zip file then copying it then renaming it back